# How to open Microsoft Excel files?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to read my Microsoft Excel files on my Android device. Is there anything built-in natively? Is there an application for viewing and editing Excel files on Android?

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Documents To Go](http://www.dataviz.com/products/documentstogo/android/). You can create, edit, and view MS Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and even PDF docs.

As a free alternative, you can upload your Excel docs to Google Docs and use the free [GDocs](http://sites.google.com/site/gdocsforandroid/) app.

Comment: Note that you cannot edit Google Docs from an Android phone.

Comment: Note that you can now, you should now be able to edit from a mobile at the website at http://docs.google.com or by installing the official app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs More info at http://www.google.com/mobile/docs/

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ideas:

- upload it to google docs (you can do it from the browser) and view it there.
- use an office application such as [OpenOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader), [OfficeSuite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_with_reg) or [QuickOffice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qo.android.am3) or [Mobile Document Viewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.joergjahnke.documentviewer.android.free)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite app for this is [OfficeSuite Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_with_reg&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLm1vYmlzeXN0ZW1zLmVkaXRvci5vZmZpY2Vfd2l0aF9yZWciXQ..) but I got it when it was the free app of the day, so I can understand not wanting to pay $14.99... it is a great program though!

Answer (score 0):

[OfficeSuite](http://www.mobisystems.com/mobile/android/category/office-family/) is a great app for viewing and editing documents. There are two versions one as a [Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.office) (free), the other as a [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_registered) (payable) version. There is also a [trial version of the Pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_with_reg), so you could try it out if you decide to buy it.

[image: Slideshow of the apps screenshots]

What you get:

- File browser
- Text document module
- Spreadsheet module
- Presentation module
- PDF Reader
- Email reader

Supported formats:

- Text format - DOC and DOCX, DOCM, RTF, TXT, LOG
- Spreadsheet - XLS, XLSX, XLSM and CSV
- Presentation - PPT, PPTX, PPS, PPSX, PPTM and PPSM
- Other formats - PDF, EML, ZIP

Bonus:

- OfficeSuite Pro is the only Android mobile office application that allows opening of password protected documents (*taken from the Google Play site*)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [WPS Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng&hl=en). It's free and I find it very useful.

Here is a list of features highlighted on official page:

**Spreadsheets**:

- Fully compatible with Microsoft Excel
- Includes dozens of formula and function shortcuts
- Supports pivot tables, freeze frames, sorting, table styles and more
- Insert charts, including bar, pie, line and column
- Edit cell categories (number, text, percentage, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Is [AndrOpen Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andropenoffice&hl=en_AU&gl=US) any good?

Supposedly its OpenOffice made for Android.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/252066)

Answer (score 0):

If merely viewing is your requirement, something like [XODO Docs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en_IN&gl=US) would do the best for you

For both editing and reading, the official [Microsoft Excel for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.excel&hl=en_IN&gl=US) would be the best choice