# Is there any way to install Open Office in Android?

Tags: microsoft-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good application on Android to open Microsoft Excel files?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-is-a-good-application-on-android-to-open-microsoft-excel-files)

Is there any way to install Open Office in Android Emulator, So that I can Open XLS sheet in Android Emulator for my apps.Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes, esp. since the question came from StackOverflow. However ... @abk you'll probably get better answers here if you clarify the problem you're trying to solve (reading and/or editing an excel file). Installing Open Office is probably not the only possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score -3):

yes it is android market you can install it in your device . QuickOffice is also there in Android market for reading XLS documents.

Comment: This answer is incredibly misleading. OpenOffice.org is **not** available for Android. There is an app called [OpenOffice Document reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.tomtasche.reader&feature=search_result), but this is, again, **not** OpenOffice.org itself. It's just a 3rd party app designed to read .odt and .ods files. It even states in the description that it doesn't support Microsoft Office formats!